# QGIS make round legend style fill for objects in the map

Tags: qgis, style

I have the situation as you see below:

[image]

I have the buffers 50m, which have a green color. Unfortunately in the styling in the panel, they appear as boxes. When I used the point pattern fill in order to ger rounds there, I completed another pattern on my map.

How can I make the fill round in my Layers section instead without changing the general shape on my map?

Comment: You can change the shape of legend patch in a layout but I don't think you can do it in the Layer panel

Comment: A workaround could be to add a centroid fill to your buffer, you still get a square legend but it will have a circle added (the obvious downside is that you will also get a dot displayed on your map...)

Answer (score 3):

In my example, I have a red diamond with a green buffer and the buffer appears as a green circle in the layer panel.

[image: example]

There is two different symbols on this layer. The one at the bottom is the buffer itself, a simple fill with the color you want (green here).
[image: buffer]

The filling color is transparent so it's not visible in the layer panel but in the data defined rules, I set this rule :

```
if( "id" is null, '#0ffc41','#0efc41')
```

Replace "id" with a random field of your choice.

This allows me to set a green color code is any case possible (there might be a better way to set this). But since the color picked earlier is transparent, the symbol appears as transparent but the rule then apply a green color to the buffer.

Then, to have a green dot symbol :

[image]

I set a centroid filling with the symbol of my choice, and to make it green on the layer panel and transparent on the map, I use the same technique as before but in reverse.
The symbol color is set to green but in the data defined rules I set a transparent color for all the cases possible.

```
if( "id" is null, '#00000000','#00000000')
```

Comment: Very creative workaround! I hope eventually there will be the same editing options for the symbols in the Layers Panel as there are for the Legend in the Print Layout, but this is a great solution in the meantime. I can add that the field name in the `if` needn't even exist (but using `$id` instead of `"id"` did *not* work).

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work as I still get the radius of my buffer gone. Thanks for your effort anyway.

Comment: Did you set up the two symbols for your buffer ? One for the map and one for the symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Add a copy of the layer with point symbology for the legend, but to hide this on the map, make the layer invisible, keeping instead the polygon layer for the map. So in the legend, you can only keep the point symbology, on the map only the buffer/polygon symbols.

1. Duplicate the layer.
2. In the layer styling panel, click on `Symbol` and change fill style from `Simple Fill` to `Centroid Fill`.
3. Set Opacity of the layer to 0 % (or uncheck visibility of the layer in the Layers panel): expand layer rendering at the bottom of the Layer styling panel.

[image]

Comment: Centroid fill still brings me back to the position where I was at the very beginning. I need something, which will appear as the circle but will keep the radius defined - 50m on the map.

Comment: Yes, you'll get that: initial layer keeps the radius (buffer), duplicated layer the dots in the legend. Or did I completely misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool and set a custom icon: https://yoannqdq.github.io/qgis-layer-tree-icons/ - But I think it would only work for the root level - so your classification icons wont work unfortunately.

Comment: That could be good, but I can't find circles there.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a legend patch (a circle)!
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rb3EZSs9q4w

Comment: It refers rather to a print composer. I need it in the main QGIS panel

Comment: Perhaps you can do it with geometry generator as a workaroud? But not sure it will fit your needs!

Comment: In the legend expanded dropdown I need to have circles instead of boxes, but shapes on the map must remain the same.